# Any idea what this bike is?

Tags: identify-this-bike

We received this bike from a friend that was cleaning out their garage.  There aren't any identifying badges or marks, etc., except the ID# H990320629.  We tired to find a similar frame as [seen here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SCHWINN-FRAME-AUTOCYCLE-B6-PHANTOM-BIKE-CRUISER-BICYCLE-TANK-SPRINGER-FORK-DX-S2-/391780995391?hash=item5b37f7913f:g:RMQAAOSwrhBZFInX).

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

[image: My Bike]

[image: My Bike]

Comment: Well, it's at least fairly unique.  A little hard, though, to be sure that those twisty things aren't someone's after-market embellishment.  Someone somewhere probably has the serial number decoder for old Schwinn bikes (which this very likely is).  I'm gonna say that it dates 1955-1965.

Comment: (Although, looking at the second picture it seems to be a BMX frame, making it 5-10 years newer.)  (And, while I don't know about their small bikes, Schwinn liked to use odd-sized tires on their bigger bikes.  Telling us the tire sizes stamped on the sides of the tires might be a clue.)

Comment: (On the anti-Schwinn side, they bragged about their "welded-on kickstands" for most of their bikes.  Not sure about these small ones.)

Answer (score 3):

Its not a Scwhinn at all.. Its a Lowrider Brand Bicycle.. With their Lowrider tires they send you with the bike and the cheap... They base theirs off the stingray like 65839 other makers do.. You could use the Schwinn registry to see ita not a Schwinn.. Heres why ik what that bike is.... H930701285... I OWN ONE

This is more than likely the site it was bought on..

https://www.bicycledesigner.com/bicycles/lowrider-bicycles-1.html

Answer (score 2):

Its a Schwinn Lowrider with what looks to be 16" high-spoke count wheels.

It is not a limo lowrider or stingray lowrider, just a "lowrider"  The front springer fork (suspension) and high spoke count, and banana seat have been part of the design for a long time.

As for year - the model was available from the 1960s and is still available now.  Lack of front brake implies its not recent, or its from somewhere that a single brake is legal.

Note, the rearward seating position makes this a "semi crank-forward" bike, and it would be quite hard to ride up a decent grade because it would be tippy and light on the front wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive that it's a brand called (Low Rider) which is a bite off or generic of Schwinn.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Both of the existing answers have given this name.  Is there anything you can add to make this answer worthwhile like some pictures?